# Installing Pre-render Token in htaccess file

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, prerender

I've search a few days but still have a problem with htaccess file to install **prerender.io** Token. I've got this message after saving and testing all kind of htaccess formats:

> We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet.
> Click here to see how to install the token in your middleware.

Actually all pages are cached! My project is **Reactjs** and **Codeigntier** with shared host on **Apache**.

I have a htaccess file like so:

```
# this section for forcing https and www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mokaab.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#  this is the code which provided on Prerender website
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "TOKEN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        
        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://www.mokaab.com/$2 [P,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

# this is for avoiding 404 page when refreshing page on React apps
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Furthermore I've changed their places but still have a problem!
Then I put following meta tag in **Head** section :

`<meta name="fragment" content="!">`

I think the problem is about htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file was correct! The problem is for configuration in host!
These configuration must be enable on every type of host :

```
mod_headers.c
mod_rewrite.c
mod_proxy_http.c
```

Obviously the first two option are enable on normal host but the last one need `SSH` which is unavailable!